# Не заходит в метод $.getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Просто создал новый проект на ASP.NET Core 2.0. Подключил все необходимый библиотеки.
JQoure работает без проблем. Но именно в этот метод не заходит. Апи контроллер нормально возвращает значение. Как в моем предыдущем предыдущем все тоже самое.

```
<script>
function getData(data) {

    //var x = document.getElementById("brand");
    //var option = document.createElement("option");
    //option.text = "Kiwi";
    //x.add(option);

    var url = "/api/CarData";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

        var x = document.getElementById("brand");

        var option = document.createElement("option");

        option.text = "hello";

        x.add(option)





    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    getData();
});
```

```
 <form>
            <select id="brand" size="8">
                <option>Apple</option>

            </select>
        </form>
```

Сам селект находится если ракоментировать строчки выше. Но почему не заходит в метод гедджсон...хз...Все библиотеки подклюены. Делал так же как в моем предыдущем проекте и там все пашет. В чем я  налажал?

Comment: "Апи контроллер нормально возвращает значение." - какое? Что придет, если Вы введете url запроса в адресную строку браузера?

Answer (score 0):

Так как Вы вызываете `$.getJSON`, делать `$.parseJSON(data);` - не следует. `data` - это уже js объект.

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    //var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    var obj = data;
    console.log(typeof obj, obj);

    var x = document.getElementById("brand");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "hello";
    x.add(option)
});
```